# Inverse Z transform

Tags: residue-calculus, z-transform

I am trying to perform an inverse Z transform on the equation below. I need to get from Z domain to the time domain. From what I've seen, Wolfram Alpha multiplies the result with the Heaviside function. I have managed to get almost to the same result using the Residue Theorem but I don't have the Heaviside function part.
What am I doing wrong?

Equation on Wolfram Alpha: [W/A](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse%20Z%20transform%20of%20((1-e%5E(-2*h))%2F(2*(z-1)*(z-e%5E(-2*h)))))

Comment: I cannot find my crystal ball, sorry.

Comment: This is the correct result $$\frac{1}{2} \left(1-e^{-2 h (n-1)}\right) \theta (n-2)$$
I used residue then applied Z transform and did not get the initial function while with the previous one I got the exact function we started from.

Comment: So to get the correct result you didn't use the residue?